# File after git pull does not have changes

Tags: git, gitlab

I have made a change to a file on one machine and pushed it. I can see my change on GitLab online, but when I run the following commands the file doesn't get updated. I realize I can just delete the repo and git clone it again, but I'm trying to understand Git more. What am I doing wrong?

First attempt:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\functions>git pull
Already up to date.
```

Second attempt (cbd85fc is what shows on GitLab too):

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\functions>git fetch --all
Fetching origin

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\functions>git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at cbd85fc commitmessage

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\functions>git pull
Already up to date.
```

Comment: If the remote is at cbd85fc and you are at cbd85fc, they are identical (except for local untracked files).

Comment: I might sound really stupid but I did this once. Did you check the branches?

Comment: @matt, I checked my untracked files with this command and it doesn't show up `git status -u`

Comment: @omarjayed, just checked them. Unfortunately was on the correct one